# Change and retain DIV Selected tag in Master Page

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, master-pages

I have a CSS class called **selected** which highlights the DIV as the current step. When they're all in separate pages, I just had to move the selected word to the next DIV.

But how can I achieve the same in Master Page VB .Net? It seems to be one page for all. When the next page loads, how do I get it to highlight the next step? Thank you.

```
<div id="Div1">
    <div class="step selected" id="Div2">
        <h2>
            Join</h2>
        <img src="./assets/images/signup_arrow.png" class="selected">
    </div>
    <div class="step" id="Div3">
        <h2>
            Choose</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="step" id="Div4">
        <h2>
            INVITE</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of these controls programatically, you have to make them available server-side via the **runat="server"** attribute. Once you do that you can get a handle to the controls, either directly in the MasterPage or indirectly on constituent Controls or the Page itself via **FindControl**("Div2"), which will return an **HtmlGeneric** control that represents the div. With that you can then use it's Attributes collection to change the class (controls under System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.* lack the direct **CssClass** property that WebControls have).

There are client-side options as well.